# Determining whether a statement in the form $P \to Q$ is true or not by assuming $P \wedge \neg Q$ and giving a counterexample

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Can we determine whether a statement in the form $P \to Q$ is true or not by assuming $P \wedge
 \neg Q$ and giving a counterexample ?

if it is not the case, why ?

Edit: I'm asking this as a general method for showing the truth/falsity of a statement in the form of $P \to Q$.I mean, for example, we can prove this kind of a statement by assuming $P \wedge Q$ and deriving a contradiction, and I'm asking that what if I don't derive a contradiction, but rather find an example that contradicts with the assumption $P \wedge Q$, so that I can say $P \wedge Q$ doesn't hold every time, so does this imply that $P \to Q$ holds every time ?

Comment: Unclear what are you asking. Prove **and** give a counterexample ? To prove it you have to use a *proof system*; if you give a counterxample, this means that it is not provable. Use truth table.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I edited my question.

Comment: If I have understood well, $P \land \lnot Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot (P \to Q)$. Thus, assuming $P \land \lnot Q$ and deriving a **contradiction** it is enough to prove $P \to Q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I know the method of contradiction while show that a statement is true, but I'm asking, particularly, not deriving a contradiction but rather just giving a example that contradicts with $P \wedge \neg Q$.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a "counterexample" to $P\land\neg Q.$ Could you tell us what statements $P$ and $Q$ are?

Comment: @bof there is not actually statement in my question.I'm asking this as a method for general.

Comment: @bof What I meant by "counterexample" for $P \wedge \neg Q$ is the following: Since we are assuming that $P \wedge \neg Q$, I will show you a case that it will contradict with the assumption $P \wedge \neg Q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I did not get it what did you mean by that comment

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA it is not the question that I'm asking.

Comment: If you assume $P \land Q$ and derive a contradiction, you have proved $\lnot (P \land Q)$, but this is **not** equivalent to $P \to Q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA First of all, I did not get it how you related this with my other post.Secondly, I have already know what you have said, but I'm specifically asking  what about if I don't derive a contradiction after assuming $P \wedge \neg Q$, but instead __give an example__that is contradicts with the assumption $P \wedge \neg Q$.I'm not deriving anything just finding an example.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p\rightarrow q\equiv \sim p \lor q\equiv \sim ( p \land \sim q)$, so if $ ( p \land \sim q)$ is **TRUE** then $p\rightarrow q$ is **FALSE** and vice-versa.

**EDIT**

> I'm asking this as a general method for showing the truth/falsity of a statement in the form of $p\rightarrow q$.

I hope this may add something to understand the meaning (truth or falsity) of the conditional $p\rightarrow q$.

Suppose you give a statement here in MSE "If my friend knows some Mathematics then I will join MSE". Here

$p$: My friend knows Mathematics.

$q$: I join MSE.

Then what you said is $p\rightarrow q$. Now, suppose one of the old member of MSE files a case against you and imagine that you are in the court for hearing. See the following possibilities:

$1$. Your friend knows Mathematics ($T$) and you join MSE ($T$), then you are innocent ($T$)  (as you stated nothing wrong in your statement) i.e. $T\rightarrow T\equiv T$.

$2$.Your friend knows Mathematics ($T$) and you dn't join MSE ($F$), then you are not innocent ($F$)  (as you contradicted your statement) i.e. $T\rightarrow F\equiv F$.

$3$.Your friend doesn't know Mathematics ($F$) and you join MSE ($T$), then you are innocent ($T$)  (as you never stated anything about his unawareness of Mathematics) i.e. $F\rightarrow T\equiv T$.

$4$.Your friend doesn't know Mathematics ($F$) and you do not join MSE ($F$), then you are innocent ($T$)  (as you never stated anything about his unawareness of Mathematics) i.e. $F\rightarrow F\equiv T$.

**Note**: You cannot be punished for what you never claimed or stated. Consider another innocent statement, "If I am the creator of this world then elephants fly in the sky".

Comment: It is definitely not a answer to my question.Plus, the notation you used doesn't express what you are trying to say.

Comment: I edited my question, I hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, but could you describe my question with your own words.